# What is interaction between paralel iterators from Rayon and blocking HTTP from ureq in Rust?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, blocking, rayon, ureq

If I have a vec of 100 urls and make paralel iterator which makes 100 blocking HTTP requests, is the first request blocking the rest of them or can the all be made before some of them finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Rayon` method, it creates a [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/struct.ThreadPool.html). You can create your own `ThreadPool` with number of threads you want to run in parallel.

So in your particular case, each request will block the thread it executed in, but threads will be run in parallel. In other words, if you have pool with 3 threads, then it will execute 3 requests in parallel.

```
Vec: [#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8] // list of requests
time ->

thread 1: #1...#4......#8
thread 2: #2.....#6...#7
thread 3: #3....#5
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if the "blocking" means on a higher level than the threads produced by rayon